# setText from inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I run a setText command inside of a fragment activity to try and set the text of a textView in the parent activity, but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
TextView text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.status);
        text.setText("Text from a fragment");
```

I don't get an error in eclipse, but I get a null pointer exception during runtime. Of course it happens at the line where I setText. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your NPE will probably be because `R.id.status` is probably not defined in the fragment's view.

`getView()` will return the view that is generated in your Fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

Are you trying to set a TextView in your Activity from a (secondary) FragmentActivity or trying to set a TextView in your FragmentActivity from a Fragment?

If it's the 1st option, you'll want to do something like use a message handler and pass the 2nd Activity a message. I don't think this is what you're asking though.

If you're wanting to set a TextView from a Fragment, the general way to do that is to define an interface on your FragmentActivity with a method (`updateText()` for example) and get the Fragment to call the method. The Activity then handles the TextView update, which works nicely because it can call `getView()` which will return the view you're looking for. It's similar to my answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573712/why-direct-communication-between-fragments-is-not-recommended/11573912#11573912)

Comment: Yeah, this goes against fragments because it shouldn't have ties with the activity, but it's necessary in my predicament.

Answer (score 5):

Use getActivity(). It will cause the findViewById() method to start the search at the base activity and bubble up until it finds your "r.id.status".

```
TextView text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.status);
text.setText("Text from a fragment");
```