# Android why Fragments should not directly communicate with each other?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, modularity

I have an `Activity A` hosting two main `Fragment F1 and F2`. Both `F1` and `F2` have nested `Fragment`, each with its own `Listener` interface for exchanging data.

From what I understood from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142956/sending-data-from-nested-fragments-to-parent-fragment), the activity `A`:

- needs to know every single interface declared by the fragments hosted by `F1` and `F2`
- needs to route the events generated by the fragments in `F1` and `F2` to the correct main fragment, `F1` or `F2`.

If I understood correctly, there is no modularity in this approach: the activity needs to know everything about both the fragments it hosts (`F1` and `F2`) and the fragments that are nested in `F1` and `F2`.

Am I correct? For sure, I am very confused ...

Comment: Your nested fragments can talk directly to their parent fragments using `getParentFragment()` if that is what you ask? Thus no need to have nested child fragments talk to Activity in all cases. If you need more freedom of how your Activities/Fragments communicate, you can use EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus, it essentially allows you to broadcast objects across your app. I use it to e.g. say 'update ui' whenever db values has changed. Then whichever Activities/Fragments are alive and listening will then update the ui accordingly. Seems lighter than setting up callbacks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [**Communicating with Other Fragments**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) tutorial, it says that:

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

The reason for this is that `Fragment`s are fluid & dynamic UI components that may fade in and out of view. Only the hosting `Activity` is capable of determining if a `Fragment` is added to the UI or has been detached from it.

> If I understood correctly, there is no modularity in this approach:
>   the activity needs to know everything about both the fragments it
>   hosts (`F1` and `F2`) and the fragments that are nested in `F1` and `F2`.

The `Fragment`s are "modular" in the sense that they are totally independent & reusable UI blocks. Also, they are "modular" because their interfaces are well defined and explicitly implemented by the hosting `Activity`. Anywhere you drop that `Fragment` in, if the `Activity` implements the callback interface defined in the `Fragment`, then the `Activity` "chooses" what to do depending on whether the `Fragment` is added / attached to the UI or not.

If we loosely apply the `MVC` way of thinking here, the hosting `Activity` acts as a `controller` of sorts between two `views` which are the `Fragment`s. Of course this is just a loose analogy, but hopefully you get the picture.

**Further considerations:**

There is an alternative to this approach: a method called `getParentFragment()` that a nested `Fragment` can use to get a reference to the "outside" `Fragment`.

**References:**

**1.** [**Why direct communication between fragments is not recommended?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573712/why-direct-communication-between-fragments-is-not-recommended).

**2.** [**Communicating with other fragments or to activity**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/communicating-with-other-fragments-or-to-activity).

**3.** [**Fragment question: inter-fragment communication?**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/NBlMJnMaGbo).

Comment: Thank you, that's how I understood. It's not very elegant: if the activity has one fragment (or more) hosting 100 fragments, the activity needs to implement 100 different interfaces, when these interfaces are just for communicating between the main fragments and its children.